# swift error: Use of 'centralManager' refers to instance method rather than var 'centralManager' in module

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have an Obj-C app that imports an Obj-C static lib  which contains a .swift file with func run_central().

I can't get the app to reference run_central() and get the build error.

Here is Obj-C app project and its imported Obj-C static library Hub_lib that also contains (ie. imports) the .swift file....

```
ObjC app project has this file........

ViewController.mm  .....................     (is .mm because it imports C++ lib)

. . .


- (IBAction)run_simple_central:(id)sender 
{
    Hub_lib* hub_lib = [Hub_lib new];
    [hub_lib run_central]; <<<<<<<<<<<<<  No visible @interface for Hub_lib' declares the selector 'run_central'
}

@end


ObjC static library Hub_lib project has these files........  

Hub_lib-Bridging-Header.h  ............................  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   EMPTY -- NO CODE
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

BLE.swift file ..........................

import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import os

var centralManager: CBCentralManager?

class BLE_Central: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate
{
. . .
    public func run_central()   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  THE FUNCTION
    {
        Hub_lib.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
    }
```

Comment: `run_central` is a `BLE_Central` method, not a `Hub_lib` one. WHat's the link between the two of them?

Comment: BLE_Central.swift is a source file.  Hub_lib is Xcode project that contains (ie. imports) BLE_Central.swift

Comment: are you able to "reach" `BLE_Central *ble = [BLE_Central new]; [ble run_central|;` from a objc file `.m` in project `Hub_lib`, then you are close to solve it.

Comment: BLE_Central *ble = ...  is not in the lib; it is in the app that imports the lib.

Comment: hehe, meant not you have to place it in the lib, just for testing if you can reach the class method already from within the lib (objc). Because if you can not, it's clearly not exposed.

Comment: Thanks, Ol Sen. (love your icon, BTW)  QUESTION: The Hub_lib-Bridging-Header.h has no code.  Is import of .swift supposed to add interface to it?  Or do I do that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access control keyword **public** in swift does not make your `func run_central()` available to objective-c in a project as is. It just gives you control of the access level of your function in the swift module.
[docs.swift.org - Access Levels for Frameworks](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID9)

> When you develop a framework, mark the public-facing interface to that framework as **open** or **public** so that ***it can be viewed and accessed by other modules***, such as an app that imports the framework.

When used in projects targeting a frameworks it (*public*) should publish the function in its generated header file.
[Apple Docs - Import Code Within a Framework Target](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c#3024308)

Following the instructions for [bridging to Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c),
 to make your function available you need to expose it via **objc**

```
@objc public func run_central() { /* ... */ }
```

This should allow you to call your `NSObject` inherited swift class `BLE_Central` from within Objective-C via

```
BLE_Central *ble = [BLE_Central new];
[ble run_central];
```

Now the difficulties come up because `class BLE_Central` is not **public** nor is it exposed from swift via **objc** in a project that has no knowledge of a header declaring this. Leading to the clue you have to

```
#import <Hub_lib/Hub_lib-Swift.h>
```

to declare its content in your project that makes use of your framework or module.
Where the naming convention say the import rule should look like ...

```
#import <ProductName/ProductModuleName-Swift.h>
```

PS: while **objc** exposes a function or class to objective-c in the same project,
 **nonobjc** does the [opposite](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID588).

> The nonobjc attribute tells the compiler to make the declaration unavailable in Objective-C code, even though it’s possible to represent it in Objective-C.

Comment: don't forget you can check what is generated in the swift header `<Hub_lib/Hub_lib-Swift.h>` when cmd clicking on the `#import` rule. There you should see also that `Hub_lib`(actually BLE_Central) has a method named `-(void)run_central;` If not, there is stuff to be done.

Comment: The Hub_lib-Bridging-Header.h file still has no code.  Do I fill it in manually?

Comment: Should I set "Defines Module" to YES or NO? Am I importing within "App Target" or "Framework Target"?  I don't understand difference. I created a new Xcode app project, not a new framework.

Comment: `DEFINES_MODULE` is a packaging setting to your project named `Hub_lib` which is to be used as module name somewhere else, in this case `YES`. Importing is declaring where you want to be able to use the declared stuff. An App Target (aka underlaying project) can make use of a Framework that (should) have its own target respective underlaying project settings. When you manage to code the Framework in the same workspace as your App you will have (2) targets in your workspace. One that belongs to the Framework, one that belongs to your App, where the app makes use of the framework.

Comment: `Hub_lib-Bridging-Header.h` is used to declare objc (interfaces) to swift module (all swift files within same project). So if you want to use objc in swift you will `#import "ObjCStuff.h"` place there. But `#import <Hub_lib/Hub_lib-Swift.h>` is generated (frmwrk) header to expose it to objc. Inside the frmwrk you could use `#import "Hub_lib-Swift.h"` to expose swift to objc (`.m`) inside the framework if needed. The misleading point is, this `..-Swift.h` is a generated file that is depending on your frmwrk project settings and `objc func` declarations